# How to insert number into 4 bytes

Tags: c#, .net

I have the number 1 and 4 bytes that represent my value (in this is - 1) and i want to insert this number into my bytes so it need to be `00 00 00 01` and this is what i have try and the result is `10 00 00 00`:

```
array[Index + 2] = (byte)(num & 0xFF);
array[Index + 3] = (byte)((num>> 8) & 0xFF);
array[Index + 4] = (byte)((num>> 16) & 0xFF);
array[Index + 5] = (byte)((num>> 24) & 0xFF);
```

I will glad for some help

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want.

```
array[Index + 5] = (byte)(num & 0xFF);
array[Index + 4] = (byte)((num>> 8) & 0xFF);
array[Index + 3] = (byte)((num>> 16) & 0xFF);
array[Index + 2] = (byte)((num>> 24) & 0xFF);
```

`num & 0xFF` it will make 0 all bits except first rightmost 8.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bit converter:

```
byte[] numberToByteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(1);
```

One will be in the least significant cell that is in numberToByteArray[0], that is: `00 00 00 01`.

If you want the value to be in numberToByteArray[3] instead - reverse the result:

```
byte[] reversedResult = numberToByteArray.Reverse().ToArray();
```

After reversing it that's the result: `01 00 00 00`

Comment: What about byte order?

Comment: This is also not portable.  `BitConverter` returns different values based off of the executing CPU's endianness.  To work cross-platform, check `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to be mixed, typically, to represent the decimal 1, you would have one of `00 00 00 01` (big endian), `01 00 00 00` (little endian) or `00 01 00 00` (middle-endian). What you have appears to be similar to middle endian, but on a byte level.

You will have to flip the nibbles yourself:

```
var Index = 0;
var array = new byte[7];
var num = 0x87654321;

var t = num;
array[Index + 2] = (byte)((t & 0xF) << 4 | (t & 0xf0) >> 4); t >>= 8;
array[Index + 3] = (byte)((t & 0xF) << 4 | (t & 0xf0) >> 4); t >>= 8;
array[Index + 4] = (byte)((t & 0xF) << 4 | (t & 0xf0) >> 4); t >>= 8;
array[Index + 5] = (byte)((t & 0xF) << 4 | (t & 0xf0) >> 4);

Console.Writeline("{0:X2} {1:X2} {2:X2} {3:X2}", array[2], array[3], array[4], array[5]);
// prints: 12 34 56 78
```

**Edit:** if you are looking for it to be big-endian, then Hamlet Hakobyan's answer is appropriate.